# Hamster cage's tunnels seem to be too small

Tags: containment, hamsters

I'm looking at different cages for our hamster (can't remember what kind she is - she's just average size) but the tubes/tunnels that come with them seem really narrow for our hamster.

Can they fit through a tube that is smaller than they are?

Comment: Small animals can often squeeze through any opening they can get their heads through.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know that much about hamsters, but based on just looking at them a few times, I know that hamsters tend to skrunch up normally, which makes them look fatter, but in reality they can actually fit through small spaces by stretching out.